# My Simple Contact.php form is not working

Tags: php, contacts

I am working on one website and wanted to add a contact form in it but when I tried to create simple contact for testing with fields that I am going to add on the website later it's not working properly.
I have tried some youtube videos for setup my contact.php form I followed every step but when I test it directly shows Error 500.

Specific Error is
**This page isn’t working**
**[www.creativeboxx.co.in](http://www.creativeboxx.co.in)** is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Here is my Testing HTML Form

```
<form action="contact-form.php" method="post"> 
    
    <input name="name" placeholder="Full Name">
    <input name="mail" placeholder="Email Address">
    <input name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number">
    <input name="reason" placeholder="Reason for Contact">
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="message"></textarea>
    <button name="submit" type="submit">Send</button>

</form>
```

I have tried with a few different PHP codes using youtube but nothing working

Here is my last used PHP code for contact.php

```
<?PHP
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST ['name'];
    $mailFrom = $_POST ['mail'];
    $mobile = $_POST ['mobile'];
    $reason = $_POST ['reason'];
    $message = $_POST ['message'];
    $mailTo = "vishal.pandya@openxcell.info";
    $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
    $txt = "New Inquiry from " .$name.".\n\n".$message;
    mail($mailTo, $reason, $txt);
    header("Location: index.html");
}
?>
```

I have learned HTML and CSS only a couple of months ago so I don't have much knowledge about PHP so guys please help me out.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you checked if your PHP script can actually send a mail? Try executing the mail() function with hardcoded values (i.e. manually set each variable).

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons for the error, what I can see :

1. please check if the PHP file name is: **contact-form.php** and it is in the same directory with your HTML code file (index.html or whatever)
2. `mail($mailTo, $reason, $txt);`  => this function **mail()** is inbuild function in PHP.
   to use **mail()** function, you will have to edit php.ini. and this function sometime creates issues and sometime not able to send email.

to send an email please use this library : [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) . this is a more widely used and battle-tested library, so it may help you to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to know what error is happening on your page.

This way you can display errors in your page:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

when you hit the submit form you need to stop the redirect in order to view the error:

`header("Location: index.html");` you need to disable this line to view the error

and most importantly when/if you solve the problem don't forget to remove the display error message (above code) because that would cause problems later on.